# Can not redirect to new link

Tags: redirect, apache2.4

I'm setting to redirect my link to the new link, but I tried to set many times in vhost, the setting didn't work well. Please help me.
I'm using apache 2.4

The old link: /ac/bc?pagename=Test/TestClassfication&id=006&level=001

The new link: /ac/test/006.html

My setting:
RewriteRule   ^/ac/bc?pagename=Test/TestClassfication&id=006&level=001$      /ac/test/006.html       [R=301,L]

I also checked  some tools online with this setting but it didn't work.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pagename\=Test/TestClassfication($|&)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id\=006($|&)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)level\=001($|&)

RewriteRule ^ac/bc$ /ac/test/006.html? [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, thanks guys.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ac/bc

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pagename=Test/TestClassfication&id=006&level=001$

RewriteRule ^(.*) /ac/test/006.html? [R=301,L]